# how to have ad-blocked browsing?

Tags: browser

I use Firefox and uBlock on my PC to save CPU time and data. Is there a similar way to get faster browsing in Android? I prefer not to use Adblock Plus.

Comment: What reason do you have for not wanting to use Adblock Plus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox Mobile **supports add-ons**! Including but not limited to: **uBlock Origin**. So install Firefox and add uBlock. Should run just like your desktop. Problem solved!

Fun bonus: Firefox Mobile's user agent string causes some funny stuff I've noticed (check Amazon.com). You can get an add-on to fix that, too, though! Just add "AppleWebKit/9999" to the user agent string and suddenly websites are prettier :3

Answer (score 4):

AdBlock does not make your browsing faster. It simply blocks ads. *Maybe it does, but that's probably insignificant.*

If you want to improve browsing speed, try [Opera Max - Data manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.max&hl=en).

> Opera Max is a free, data-savings and data-management app that extends
>   your data plan. With Opera Max, you can easily manage your data by
>   monitoring daily data usage and limit data-hogging apps to Wi-Fi only.
>   Opera Max also provides data savings by compressing videos, photos,
>   media and more on almost all of your favorite apps and websites -
>   without any noticeable loss of quality. Data overage fees are a thing
>   of the past with Opera Max!

You can also try [Opera](http://www.opera.com/mobile/operabrowser/android)'s Off-Road feature (different from Opera Max).

> **Save time and money** On a slow connection? Or, need to control your
>   Android phone or tablet’s data use? Switch to Off-Road mode in Opera
>   to save data and browse faster.

Or if you already have the [Chrome Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome&hl=en) installed, enable `Reduce Data Usage` in its settings.

> **Save Data** - reduce mobile data usage by up to 50% while browsing

Answer (score 2):

If you have a rooted device. I suggest installing [Ad Away](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2190753)

Answer (score 1):

The  free and open-source web browser, [image: Brave logo] [**Brave**](https://brave.com/) contains built-in ad and tracker blocking. [Google Play Store page](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brave.browser&hl=en)

> Brave blocks unwanted content by default and keeps count.
> Popular sites often host multiple ads and as many as 70 trackers per site.

> Browse confidently with default settings that block phishing, malware, and malvertising. Also, plugins, which have proven to be a security risk, are disabled by default.

Other browsers with built-in ad blockers:

**[Firefox Focus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.focus&hl=en)**

> The new Firefox Focus automatically blocks a wide range of online trackers — from the moment you launch it to the second you leave it.
> AUTOMATIC PRIVACY - Blocks a wide range of common Web trackers without any settings to set.
> BROWSE FASTER - By removing trackers and ads, Web pages may require less data and load faster

Answer (score 0):

There is a fast browser that block ads called "uc browser" you should download the latest version from google play because this feature is only found in the newset version

Answer (score 0):

Android Ad block from browsers and app as well

Block all ads by replacing hosts file. Easiest way to block ads :) No app or proxy required.

**Steps**

1. Root required
2. Install android emulator or use file browser to replace the hosts file
3. Replace the hosts file from the repo (https://github.com/SangramChavan/Android-Ad-block) to the existing hosts file present in /etc/hosts